# Kubernetes Missing secret file with error Error: secret "env" not found

Tags: kubernetes, sealedsecret

When I deploy the new release of the Kubernetes app I got that error

```
Error: secret "env" not found
```

[image]

even I have env in **Custom Resource Definitions** --> **sealedsecrets.bitnami.com**

[image]

**env.yaml**

```
apiVersion: bitnami.com/v1alpha1
kind: SealedSecret
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: env
  namespace: api
spec:
  encryptedData:
    AUTH_COGNITO: AgCIxZX0Zv6gcK2p ----
template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      name: env
      namespace: api
    type: Opaque
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Release.Name }}
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicas }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.imageRepository }}:{{ .Values.tag }}"
          env:
            {{- include "api.env" . | nindent 12 }}
          resources:
            limits:
              memory: {{ .Values.memoryLimit }}
              cpu: {{ .Values.cpuLimit }}
            requests:
              memory: {{ .Values.memoryRequest }}
              cpu: {{ .Values.cpuRequest }}
          {{- if .Values.healthCheck }}
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /healthcheck
              port: 4000
            initialDelaySeconds: 3
            periodSeconds: 3
            timeoutSeconds: 3
          {{- end }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: {{ .Values.imagePullSecret }}      
      {{- if .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml .Values.tolerations | indent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- if .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml .Values.nodeSelector | indent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

**UPDATE to my question**
my secrets I don't have secret called `env`

plus that error in `regcred` inside `Sealedsecrets.bitnami.com`

```
Failed to unseal: no key could decrypt secret (.dockerconfigjson)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have the "Secret" object named `env` in the cluster (not the sealedsecret object). 
Is your sealedsecrets controller actually "un-sealing" the sealedsecret and creating the secret ? 
Can you share logs from the sealed secrets controller ?

Comment: no I dont have secret with env name , and sorry I dont know if my sealedsecrets controller  "un-sealing"  my object or not

Comment: The sealed secrets controller is supposed to un-seal/decrypt the sealedsecrets object and then create a "secret" object with that data. Check the logs of the sealed secrets controller.

Comment: yea I see he cant with that error Failed to unseal: no key could decrypt secret (.dockerconfigjson)

Comment: Did you encrypt the secret ".dockerconfigjson" from the key that sealedsecrets is using ? Seems like an issue with sealed secrets key settings and encryption 

https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets/blob/main/docs/bring-your-own-certificates.md

Comment: Thanks, Hazim for the help the issue was I encrypt with wrong namespace

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ran `kubeseal` against the wrong Kubernetes cluster or you tried to edit the name or namespace after encrypting without enabling those in the encryption mode. More likely the first.

Answer (score 1):

even @coderanger answer it I would like to add more details

I made a mistake I was running the kubeSeal command with the wrong namespace( api instead of api2) then change it in the converted file

```
KubeSeal < input.yaml > env.yaml -o yaml
```

**input.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: env
  namespace: api
type: Opaque
stringData:
  DB_USER: "userName"
  DB_PASSWORD: "password"
```